# Display image below product price based on product category on WooCommerce shop and archive pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, categories

I'm currently working on a WooCommerce-shop for a client. She is selling jewellery and wants me to display a gold/silver circle underneath the product-price in the product grid (as seen on the screenshot).

[image]

---

My idea is something like getting the category with something like that:

```
<?php if (is_product_category('979')) then do something ?>
```

I already tried to echo an  and inserted this into `wc-template-functions.php` --> product-title-loop but it did not work out.

Would be glad if someone could point me in the right direction

Comment: Maybe this is what you need..
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-color-and-image-swatches/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"I already tried to echo an and inserted this into wc-template-functions.php"*

**Never edit core files!**

When you modify a plugin’s core files you run the risk of breaking the plugin and possibly your WordPress installation. In addition, it makes it impossible for the plugin developer to provide support for you since they have no knowledge of what you’ve changed.

---

**Use instead** the `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item` action hook in combination with [has_term()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/)

```php
function action_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item() {
    // Get the global product object
    global $product;
    
    // Is a WC product
    if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
        
        // Has term - specific categories: the term name/term_id/slug. Several could be added, separated by a comma
        if ( has_term( array( 'categorie-1' ), 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
            echo '<img src="my-image.jpg">';
        } elseif ( has_term( array( 'categorie-2' ), 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
            echo '<img src="another-image.jpg">';
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'action_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 10, 0 );
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).